# Failed to read artifact descriptor in maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aem

To resolve org.apache.sling.event.jobs,version=[1.5,2] -- Cannot be resolved error in my bundle I added the dependency in the main pom.xml. But when I try to add the same minus the version and scope in the core xml file I am getting a  Failed to collect dependencies error.

```html
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
 <artifactId>org.apache.sling.event</artifactId>
 <version>4.2.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Error is as follows: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.event:jar:4.2.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.event:jar:4.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.event:pom:4.2.0 from/to cqblueprints.releases (http://dev.cqblueprints.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/): Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: "Connection refused: connect " It is a connection error. Show more information (you can use the `-X` debug flag when you execute mvn)

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please read the following post before posting a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The issue, simply, is that the repo you are using: http://dev.cqblueprints.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ does NOT have the artifact you are looking for `org.apache.sling.event`

take a look at http://dev.cqblueprints.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/sling/ I'd expect to see `org.apache.sling.event` but I don't.

You'll have to add a different repo that has the artifact, maybe Maven central or the Adobe repo.
see this: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SetUpTheAdobeMavenRepository.html

Also, the version you are specifying is `4.2.2` you have to check what version is provided by AEM by going to `/system/console/bundles` and looking for `org.apache.sling.event` and use that bundle's version.